# Accessing OneToMany elements using play

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I am a Java developer, and I also did some Ruby on the side in the last year.
I recently discovered, the [play framework](https://www.playframework.com/), which sounds to me like the best of both worlds.

I am trying to create my first application, and there is something that I really can't seem to find in the documentation : 
How do you access the parents / children in OneToMany relationships?

My project contains a Project model, which can have several Milestones. It is defined as such :

```
@Entity
public class Project extends Model {

    @Id
    public String id;

    public String name;
    public int number;

    @OneToMany
    public Milestone milestone;
}
```

My milestones are also really simple :

```
@Entity
public class Milestone extends Model{

    @Id
    public String id;

    @ManyToOne
    public Project project;

    public String name;
    public Date expectedEnd;
}
```

Now, say I want to list all the milestone of a project, or add a milestone to a project.

In rails, I would do something like that in my html [templates](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates):

```
@project.milestones
```

but if I try that with play I get an error, as milestones is not defined.

```
value milestones is not a member of models.project
```

I also tried to do

```
@project.milestones.size()
```

as I would expect to get a list back (one to many), but this apparently doesn't work.

```
value size is not a member of model.Milestone
```

Can you please tell me how I am supposed to get the milestones ? 
Conversely, how do I get the project of a milestone?

Thanks!

Comment: I'll run the program again to get the precise error, but as I wrote : milestones is not defined as a variable in the first case, and with size() I get a method not defined error as well, since milestone seems to be a single entity :).

Comment: Edited as requested :). Playing DOTA while creating the question didn't help :).

Comment: :) Shouldn't one-to-many be a collection in your `Project` mapping?

Comment: Hum, I have followed the eabean tutorial : https://ebean-orm.github.io/. They don't use collections as far as i can see. I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
@Entity
public class Project extends Model {

    @Id
    public String id;

    public String name;
    public int number;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
    public java.util.List<Milestone> milestones = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Milestone extends Model{

    @Id
    public String id;

    @ManyToOne
    public Project project;

    public String name;
    public Date expectedEnd;
}
```

so you can use them in the vie ie. like:

```
<ul>
@for(milestone <- project.milestones){
    <li>@milestone.name</li>
}
</ul>
```